# Indexing tensor with index matrix in theano?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, theano

I have a theano tensor A such that A.shape = (40, 20, 5) and a theano matrix B such that B.shape = (40, 20). Is there a one-line operation I can perform to get a matrix C, where C.shape = (40, 20) and C(i,j) = A[i, j, B[i,j]] with theano syntax?

Essentially, I want to use B as an indexing matrix; what is the most efficient/elegant to do this using theano?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(4 * 2 * 5).reshape(4, 2, 5)
B = np.arange(4 * 2).reshape(4, 2) % 5

C = A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis], np.arange(A.shape[1]), B]
```

So you can do the same thing in theano:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

AA = T.tensor3()
BB = T.imatrix()

CC = AA[T.arange(AA.shape[0]).reshape((-1, 1)), T.arange(AA.shape[1]), BB]

f = theano.function([AA, BB], CC)

f(A.astype(theano.config.floatX), B)
```