# advanced 3d indexind in theano

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

My question is very similar to
[Indexing tensor with index matrix in theano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947726/indexing-tensor-with-index-matrix-in-theano)
except that I have 3 dimensions. At first I want to got it working in numpy. With 2 dimensions there is no problem:

```
>>> idx = np.random.randint(3, size=(4, 2, 3))
>>> d = np.random.rand(4*2*3).reshape((4, 2, 3))
>>> d[1]
array([[ 0.37057415,  0.73066383,  0.76399376],
       [ 0.12155831,  0.12552545,  0.87648523]])
>>> idx[1]
array([[2, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
>>> d[1][np.arange(d.shape[1])[:, np.newaxis], idx[1]]
array([[ 0.76399376,  0.37057415,  0.73066383],
       [ 0.87648523,  0.87648523,  0.87648523]])  #All correct
```

But I have no idea how to make it works with all 3 dimensions. Example of failed try:

```
>>> d[np.arange(d.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis], np.arange(d.shape[1]), idx]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,1) (2,) (4,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
d[
    np.arange(d.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis],
    np.arange(d.shape[1])[:, np.newaxis],
    idx
]
```

You need the index arrays to collectively have broadcastable dimensions

Comment: Thank you, that's correct. I promise try to understand how does it works )